# Is it ok to quote a line from a fantasy book in a scientific paper?

Tags: publications, quotation

I am writing a scientific pre-print and I found a widely known quote from Tolkien that would be very relevant to my introduction, is it appropriate to include it or would it sound unprofessional?

Comment: Depends upon your journals and subfield. Some journals allow you to start of sections with quotes. Others do not. I've seen books in ecology reference relevant quotes. For example, Hal Caswell references _Alice in Wonderland_ in his book on matrix models.

Comment: @RichardErickson Books are different from journal papers, though. In my experience this is much more common in books than in articles.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I agree

Comment: Somewhat between a paper and a book is the book chapter *The historical development of uniform, proximal, and nearness concepts in topology* (freely available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264960539_The_Historical_Development_of_Uniform_Proximal_and_Nearness_Concepts_in_Topology)) in which it seems about every other page has a quote. The quotes are from the 1979 movie [Being There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_There), [Jerome K. Jerome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_K._Jerome), Lewis Carroll, [Edward Lear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Lear), and others.

Comment: Are you somewhat famous (at least a prof)? Then you could get away with this more easily.

Comment: @user111388 I am not famous at all but it would be sad to accept that only famous people have the privilege of doing that

Answer (score 3):

It might well sound unprofessional, but most people would forgive you. If it "connects" people to your topic it might be worth the risk. But Tolkien, in particular, is best known by only a portion of the adult audience. The same is true for Frank Herbert and Robert Heinlein.

But think about what it adds to your work. If it is fairly positive, don't hesitate. If it adds very little, then give it up.

If the work is strong in general then it won't even matter if the cognoscenti roll their eyes a bit.

Comment: All those great writers are less known by the smartphone generation... and many have not read the full book just the “short” or condensed version for the exam - and how do I know - I asked the students...